# Postman: Global variable stored as string?

Tags: postman

`{{productId1}}` is equal to 1.

This is the request:

```
localhost:9000/test/product/{{productId1}}
```

It works and returns me:

```
{
  "productId": 1,
  "title": "Hat X",
  "description": "This is Hat X."
}
```

But, it is not testing:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
tests["Product ID"] = jsonData.productId === "{{productId1}}";
tests["Title"] = jsonData.title === "Hat X";
tests["Description"] = jsonData.description === "This is Hat X.";
```

Third line keeps failing. What is going on? Is it because `productId1` is read as string? If so, I tried to parse it to integer, no luck. How can I pass it without loosing the type?

I tried:

```
tests["Product ID"] = jsonData.productId === "{{productId1}}";
tests["Product ID"] = jsonData.productId === "{{$productId1}}";
tests["Product ID"] = jsonData.productId === {{productId1}};
tests["Product ID"] = jsonData.productId === productId1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the global variable in test window, you should use 'postman.getGlobalVariable()' function.

In your case, it should be like:

tests["Product ID"] = jsonData.productId === postman.getGlobalVariable("productId1");

Comment: There is definitely: Have a look here. https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/newman/1.1.4/symbols/postman.getGlobalVariable                             I have tested the above code before posting it here.

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. Please update your answer so I can upvote it, otherwise it doesn't let me do that.